# mysql query into html table

Tags: php, mysql

i have a sql query shown below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `breakup` (
  `id` int(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ORDEST` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ORDEL` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ORPATT` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ORITEM` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `ORZPC` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `ORPKG` int(7) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ORDEST` (`ORDEST`),
  KEY `ORITEM` (`ORITEM`),
  KEY `ORPATT` (`ORPATT`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AVG_ROW_LENGTH=96 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `breakup`
--

INSERT INTO `breakup` (`id`, `ORDEST`, `ORDEL`, `ORPATT`, `ORITEM`, `ORZPC`, `ORPKG`) VALUES
(1, 'COLOMBO', '20170402', '000M305', '95815', 2000, 2000),
(2, 'MM', '20170405', 'Z0505', '50968BA', 100, 100),
(3, 'MM', '20170407', 'Z3481', '91123', 1, 1),
(4, 'MM', '20170407', 'Z3481', '91127', 1, 1),
(5, 'MM', '20170407', 'Z3481', '91128', 1, 1),
(6, 'MM', '20170407', 'Z3481', '91987S', 6, 1),
(7, 'MM', '20170407', 'Z3481', '91189C', 6, 1),
(8, 'COLOMBO', '20170415', 'Z0505', '55506', 972, 972);
```

then i need to genarate php report like this by usung above data; i have tried several times and ended with an error.

[image]

Thank you

php code for table heading printing ;

```
<?php 
    $sql_e=mysql_query(
        "SELECT * FROM breakup 
        GROUP By ORDEL, ORDEST 
        ORDER BY ORDEL, ORDEST"
    ) 
    or die ("err 120"); 

    while ($row_e = mysql_fetch_array($sql_e)) { 
        $dest=$row_e['ORDEST']; 
        $ordel=$row_e['ORDEL']; 
        echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" width="150"><b>&nbsp;'.$ordel."<br>". $dest.'&nbsp;</b></td>'; 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: post the code you've tried.

Comment: post code and error

Comment: php code for table heading printing ;   <?php
     $sql_e=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM breakup  GROUP By ORDEL, ORDEST ORDER BY ORDEL, ORDEST")or die ("err 120");
     
     
      while ($row_e = mysql_fetch_array($sql_e))
        { 
     
       $dest=$row_e['ORDEST'];
       $ordel=$row_e['ORDEL'];
        
     echo  '<td align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" width="150"><b>&nbsp;'.$ordel."<br>".  $dest.'&nbsp;</b></td>'; 
        }
    ?>

Comment: Tharindu: it would be better to edit your question and post the minimal code (correctly formatted) which demonstrates the issue; with a clear description of the problem or error you're encountering.

Comment: Also you are essentially asking how to implement a "pivot table" in MySQ:  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7675121/149076 for further explanation